Google Earth Engine. Converting circular structure to JSON error
I am trying to filter road data from open street map to only roads that fall within a specified region in Earth Engine. The filterBounds commands is printing the following error:

Line 24: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'cV'
|     property 'ru' -> object with constructor 'Zp'
--- property 'src' closes the circle

My code is below, and the link to access the Earth Engine script is here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/2f9fdca3c3ac644dcee94f14e52d1d59
//Loading in the IOM imagery to improve the road network data from open street map.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Get to location and load the camp boundaries

var pointKT = ee.Geometry.Point([92.1635,21.2127]); 
Map.centerObject(pointKT); 
var campBoundaries = Map.addLayer(campBoundaries, {}, "Camp Boundaries"); 


//Add the two maps.
//Note: Some missing rasters due to IOM upload error. Still need to remove black barground from one raster
//Note2: Check dates on these images to make sure they are actually from March and July.

var campsMarch19 = Map.addLayer(campsMarch19, {}, 'NPM Drone Imagery. March 2019');

var campsJuly19 = Map.addLayer(campsJuly19, {}, 'NPM Drone Imagery. July 2019');


// Add the roads data
var roads = ee.FeatureCollection("users/salem043/Bangladesh/Camp_roads_and_paths");

// Filter roads to keep only those within camp boundaries
var roadsWithinCamps = roads.filterBounds(campBoundaries);

// Add filtered roads to the map
Map.addLayer(roadsWithinCamps, {}, 'Filtered Roads Within Camps');

// Print filtered roads to the console for inspection
print('Filtered Roads:', roadsWithinCamps);




That's a weird error because you're doing a really weird thing. You're turning campBoundaries into a Map layer and then trying to do operations with it.
var campBoundaries = Map.addLayer(campBoundaries, {}, "Camp Boundaries");  

should just be
Map.addLayer(campBoundaries, {}, "Camp Boundaries"); 

